# Hosting Page in SharePoint 2010/2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

We have SharePoint 2010 and 2013 environments. We have a request to host a page for external users, who will need access ONLY to the page. We are considering using SharePoint (either SP 2010 or SP 2013) to host the page. My question is do we need to create a new web application and configure Alternate Access Mapping (AAM) or is there another simpler option(s)?

Comment: Can you add some more details, please? Do you already have anonymous access enabled for your Web application? Do you need anonymous access or the external users must authenticate? If they do - what do you use to authenticate external users? e.g. Forms-based authentication. Why do you mention both SP2010 and SP2013? Does it matter where to host the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not enough details about your environment so I will assume a few things:

- You can use your SharePoint 2013 to host a page
- You don't currently have anonymous authentication enabled in SP2013.
- Remote users don't need to login to access the page

If these assumptions hold then these are overall steps:

- Create a new Web Application just for external users
- Enable anonymous access in Central admin and on the site collection level for the new web application
- Make sure the site is available over the internet.
- Enable "Lockdown" mode feature on that new site.
- Yes, you need alternative access mapping to be setup in central administration
- Carefully setup permissions for your new site collection to only allow permissions for the single page.